# Как добавить стили элементу, если родитель имеет другой элемент?

Tags: css, css3

Можно ли проверить следующий элемент? Допустим идёт `header`, потом `intro`. Если после `header` есть `intro`, то добавляй `header` свойства.

Пытался сделать вот так, но не работает:

```
.header + .intro .header {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Или это только JS делается?

Comment: пример https://jsfiddle.net/gbed2ykj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я знаю, вроде бы без JS это никак не реализовать, так что вот вам реализация используя JS:

```js
let hdr = document.querySelector('.header')

if(hdr.nextElementSibling.className.includes('intro')) {
  hdr.classList.add('someClass')
}
```

```css
.someClass {
  color: red;
}

.someClass::after {
  content: ' - Этот элемент имеет класс someClass.';
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Пример текста 1</div>
<div class="intro">Пример текста 2</div>
```

Подробнее о том что я использовал для JS:

- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling)
- [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/className)
- [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)
- [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Подробнее о том что я использовал для CSS:

- [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

### Обновление

Совсем недавно вышли новые версии Chrome которые поддерживают псевдокласс `:has`, Firefox также поддерживает `:has`, но его нужно включать на странице `about:config` (Поменяйте **layout.css.has-selector.enabled** на **true**), если что, решение также подходит и под Edge (начиная с 105 версии), Opera (с 91 версии) и даже для WebView на Android (начиная с 105 версии), вот решение на чистом CSS:

```css
body:has(.header + .intro) .header {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Пример текста 1</div>
<div class="intro">Пример текста 2</div>
```

Comment: На js я впринципе знал как это всё работает, думал мб как-то через css можно, но всё ровно спасибо

Comment: @Vadim по идее этого можно добиться даже на чистом CSS, но тогда это будет работать только на  Safari. (Я про псевдокласс `:has`)

Comment: @Vadim обновил ответ.